# Less is broken inside GNU Screen

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, less, tput

When using `less` or `git log`, about the first 30+ lines are missing. I'm using GNU screen in a 2x2 grid, `less` is running in the bottom right pane.

`tput lines` returns `65`, but that's the total number of lines on my actual terminal, not the number of lines in the GNU Screen pane.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are the lines of the document that you are trying to view very long and wrapping? Does `more` work (in place of `less`)?

Comment: Sounds like something isn't setting $lines appropriately.

Comment: How are you opening your desktop environment, and what terminal window do you have open for the less/screen commands?

Comment: I'm on a MBP running Terminal.